# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when install a package inside a python virtualenv using pip

Tags: python, 22.04, pip, virtualenv

a few days back my ubuntu 20.04 stopped working. even after reinstalling everything with GPU drivers, after restart my screen freezes on the motherboard company logo, maybe an update with a bug causing this issue.

so I decided to upgrade my ubuntu to 22.04 and it starts working. it has python 3.10 as the base python version, but for some projects, I use python 3.7.2, and when making a virtual environment for that and trying to install its requirements I am getting this error "**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**" and can't find any solution for that yet...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution referenced in this link https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2359.

When I was using pyenv, specifically with Ubuntu 21.04 and 22.04, i have had this same problem.

So, I installed the Python 3.5.6, in my case, using clang:

```
$ sudo apt install clang -y
$ CC=clang pyenv install 3.6.15
```